# What does 'uni' mean in unistd.h

Tags: unix, filenames, terminology, posix, header-file

What does *uni* mean in **unistd.h**

Does it mean unix? or universal?
What is it?

Comment: imho, universal standard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stuff in there is largely Unix-idiom (`chown`, `fork`, `gethostname`, `nice`), so I'm guessing that it originally did mean Unix. It's part of the POSIX standard, though, so it's no longer just Unix.