# Why is unistd.h named the way it is?

Tags: c, history, standard

Similar in spirit to this question about [the etymology of linux commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258509/etymology-of-linux-commands), I'm curious about the origin of the name of `unistd.h`.

**Does anyone know *for certain* what `unistd.h` stands for? If `unistd.h` was meant to be read as "Unix standard header", why wasn't it named `unixstd.h`?**

From the [Open Group's description of `unistd.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) (emphasis mine):

> unistd.h - **standard** symbolic constants and types

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h#:%7E:text=In%20the%20C%20and%20C,compliant%20operating%20system%20and%20compiler.) (emphasis mine):

> In the C and C++ programming languages, unistd.h is the name of the
> header file that provides access to the POSIX operating system API. It
> is defined by the POSIX.1 standard, the base of the Single **Unix**
> Specification, and should therefore be available in any
> POSIX-compliant operating system and compiler.

Putting two and two together, it looks like `unistd.h` is likely a combination of *Unix* (uni) and *standard* (std), resulting in a "Unix standard header". [Barath Ravikumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625987/barath-ravikumar) and [Vicky Chijwani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504611/vicky-chijwani) posit this in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331595/7310749) to another, unrelated Stack Overflow question:

> `<unistd.h>` , stands for unix standard header ,the name says it all.

> `unistd` **could just as well stand for "universal standard header"** (I realize that sounds a bit ridiculous). The point is, they should've named it `unixstd.h` -- instant clarity by adding just one character.

If this is true, then it's possible that the omission of a single `x` character has helped spawn more than a few questions about the C standard library and why `unistd.h` isn't part of it ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826870/about-unistd-h-header-file), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331566/c-include-unistd-h-why-not-cunistd), [example 3](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/5725#issuecomment-352522266)).

Comment: The file is much older than the standards that define it today; [here’s the 2.11BSD version](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=2.11BSD/include/unistd.h). The six-character name *might* be related to various DEC file system limitations (6.3 in DECtape etc.) but 2.11BSD had other headers with longer names.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/what-does-uni-mean-in-unistd-h

Comment: At the time unistd.h was created, UNIX was a registered trademark of AT&T and could only legally be used to describe their systems, not things like BSD - it wasn't until the mid-90's that Novell transferred the UNIX trademark to The Open Group to describe the standard.

Comment: @StephenKitt But the 2.11BSD stuff is dated 1992. Moreover, the file itself carries a 1999 stamp, and a copyright header refers to 1994.   When we look at BSD4, <unistd.h> is not yet found in 4.3 Reno. It starts appearing in BSD 4.4.  This is all well into the POSIX timeline.

Comment: @StephenKitt On the other hand, it seems, according to Google Books, that "unistd.h" occurs in the X/Open Portability Guide in from 1987. It may have been an X/Open invention?

Comment: @Kaz ah, yes, 2.11BSD kept on being modified with changes from other branches for a long time... The X/Open reference is interesting, that may well be a more likely origin.

Comment: @Kaz it shows up in the 1985 edition too.